# Reference Matrix in Pandas similar to Excel

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a reference matrix in Pandas that looks like the below image in excel. I decided upon the index and column values, by simply entering in the values for the dates myself. Then, I am able to reference each column and index value for every calculation in the matrix. The calculations below are just for display.

[image]

In Pandas, I have been using the Pivot table function to produce a similar table. However, the Pivot table only uses column values if they are present in the data. See the screenshot below for the issue. I have values for 2018-05 in the index, but it doesn't appear in the columns. As such, the data is incomplete.

Therefore the Pivot table functionality does not work for me. I need to be able to manually decide on the column headers and the index values, similar to the example above in Excel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I cannot figure this one out!

```
repayments[(repayments.top_repayment_delinquency_reason == 'misappropriation_of_funds') & (repayments.repaid_date < date.today() - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1))].pivot_table(values='amount_principal',
```

index='top_repayment_due_month', columns='repaid_month', aggfunc=sum)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in the end.

```
dates_eom = pd.date_range('2018-5-31', (date.today() + relativedelta(months=+0)), freq='M')
dates_eom = dates_eom.to_period('M')

df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates_eom, columns=dates_eom)
```